# Subreport with multiple pages breaks pagination

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am using Jaspersoft Report to compile a report that consists of a multitude of subreports.
They all have 1 Title and 1 Detail Band.

I manage to fit most of them onto one page, so up until now it was enough to put them in the Main Reports Detail/Summary Section, put a Page-Break underneath and put the next one there.
But since my Objects should be visible when working with the file, I inevitably ran out of space on the first Detail-Band of my Main Report, and added another.

The first subreport in the new Detail Band contains a list, the size of which I have no control over, since it's not a chart, the object I usually work with. So it now spans ~ 2 1/4 page.

I put it in the main Report, it creates it's own page just fine (starts on the page after the subreport before it ended) but when I put a page break afterwards, and add my new Subreport below, what happens is that the title of the new subreport is printed right into the 2nd page of the List, while the Detail of the new Report is printed on the page after that.

So Basically:

Design:

- Break
- Subreport 3 Pages
- Break
- Subreport 1 Page

Preview:

- Break
- Subreport
- Page 1
- Page 2 Title of the next Subreport overlapping the List
- Page 3 Details of the next Report overlapping the list
- Page 4 Empty Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brute force approach of "just put the newer Subreport onto a new Detail-Band solved the issue. Still would be nice to know a less dirty method.